# Exception when installing Gradle 2.5

Tags: command-line, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So when I attempt to run Gradle 2.5 using the `gradle` command in cmd.exe I get the following exception.

[image]

Before attempting to run the program, the gradle client gives me the correct feedback when I enter `gradle -v` into cmd.exe indicating I have successfully added it to my PATH variable.

Is this a Read Write Execute problem in my System32 folder? I am administrator and as such believe I have all permission access?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle assumes that you're running in a project directory and will create a cache in the current working directory as soon as you run anything other than `gradle -v` or `gradle --version`.

The *system32* directory is rather special, so even if you run gradle as an administrator, you might not have write permissions for it as there maybe a secondary check that Windows performs.

If you really want to do this (I don't know why you would), have you tried running the command prompt as administrator? You can right-click on any shortcut for the command prompt and select 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: Wow, missed it, so simple I can't believe it! Thanks so much.